# Extension method resolution by parameter names

Tags: c#

It seems that in C#, parameter names can participate in extension methods resolution. Here is an example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = 1.Do1(b: 1);

        var x2 = 1.Do1(c: 1);

        Console.WriteLine(x);
        Console.WriteLine(x2);
    }
}

public static class Ext1
{
    public static int Do1(this int a, int b)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

public static class Ext2
{
    public static int Do1(this int a, int c)
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

In this program, the compiler is able to infer that the first call to `Do1` is a call to `Ext1.Do1` and the second call is to `Ext2.Do1` because I specified the names of the arguments.

Is this a documented feature of C#? Where? I was not able to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's documented in the official Microsoft docs, it's called **Overload Resolution**.
Although it's a general thing (as in, it applies everywhere), so the results you're getting are normal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#overload-resolution

Quote:

> Use of named and optional arguments affects overload resolution in the
>   following ways:
>
> A method, indexer, or constructor is a candidate for execution if each
>   of its parameters either is optional or corresponds, by name or by
>   position, to a single argument in the calling statement, and that
>   argument can be converted to the type of the parameter.
>
> If more than one candidate is found, overload resolution rules for
>   preferred conversions are applied to the arguments that are explicitly
>   specified. Omitted arguments for optional parameters are ignored.
>
> If two candidates are judged to be equally good, preference goes to a
>   candidate that does not have optional parameters for which arguments
>   were omitted in the call. This is a consequence of a general
>   preference in overload resolution for candidates that have fewer
>   parameters.

Comment: Because the two methods have the exact same parameter types, I thought there is special support for this case. Thinking about this again, simply applying the rules of overload resolution makes this a normal case.

Answer (score 0):

As @Haytam point out, this process is call [Overload Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading).
It's described in the [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions) section in the [C# language specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction).

First, to find the best overload, the set of all possible overloads must be found, called applicable function members. There is a bunch of rules to find the overloads. As you might guess, the two methods are valid candidates for the method call. 
But compiler takes the more specific ones base on explicit arguments in your case.